# How to stop xgboost from printing the fited model results

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, xgboost

How to stop the priting the model when I am trying to fit the model.

```
model = xgb.XGBRegressor(
        colsample_bytree = 0.7,
        learning_rate= 0.03,
        max_depth= 10,
        min_child_weight = 5,
        n_estimators = 300,
        nthread= 4,
        #objectvie= 'reg:squarederror',
        subsample= 0.7)

model.fit(X_train, y_train, eval_set=[(X_test, y_test)], verbose=False)
```

I want to avoid printing below in a blue box.

```
XGBRegressor(base_score=None, booster=None, callbacks=None,
             colsample_bylevel=None, colsample_bynode=None,
             colsample_bytree=0.7, early_stopping_rounds=None,
             enable_categorical=False, eval_metric=None, feature_types=None,
             gamma=None, gpu_id=None, grow_policy=None, importance_type=None,
             interaction_constraints=None, learning_rate=0.03, max_bin=None,
             max_cat_threshold=None, max_cat_to_onehot=None,
             max_delta_step=None, max_depth=10, max_leaves=None,
             min_child_weight=5, missing=nan, monotone_constraints=None,
             n_estimators=300, n_jobs=None, nthread=4, num_parallel_tree=None,
             predictor=None, ...)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is printed when "model.fit" is the most below. Add the following codes and it won't print again:

```
model = xgb.XGBRegressor(
        colsample_bytree = 0.7,
        learning_rate= 0.03,
        max_depth= 10,
        min_child_weight = 5,
        n_estimators = 300,
        nthread= 4,
        #objectvie= 'reg:squarederror',
        subsample= 0.7)

model.fit(X_train, y_train, eval_set=[(X_test, y_test)], verbose=False)
#add example:
y_pred_xg = model.predict(X_test)
```